# Weird invalid syntax in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run a python script in the Mac Terminal with `python test.py`.

The problem is that I getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import agent as a
  File "/home/test/script/agent.py", line 5
    budget: None
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

why this line `budget: None`is giving a `SyntaxError`?

the original code:

```
class Agent:
    budget: None
    budget_left: None
    (....)
```

When I run the script in PyCharm works just fine.

Comment: are you running it using Python 2?

Comment: should be `budget = None`

Comment: @UnholySheep is python 3.5.2

Comment: What do you expect this to do? Set an attribute to `None` or type annotate it?

Comment: @hop I don't know too much Python.  I was trying to emulate some kind of "variable declaration".

Comment: @exsnake: beware! `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2 on macOS.

Comment: @exsnake: please go through the python tutorial on python.org. there are no kinds of variable declaration in python. if you want to assign to an attribute, us `=`.

Answer (score 3):

It's giving a syntax error because, well, that is invalid syntax. You don't define attributes like that; you need to use assignment.

```
class Agent:
    budget = None
    budget_left = None
```

Note, though, defining these as class attributes probably [isn't what you want](https://sopython.com/canon/17/class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes/).

Comment: @exsnake BTW It 'works' (does not raise an error or perform assignment) in Py3.6 because of variable annotation

Comment: It is valid syntax in Python 3. Not very useful to annotate an attribute as None, but hey…

Comment: Is being imported and used. must be for @Chris_Rands comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just put '=' for the variables and you are done.

```
budget = None
```

Read this for more on the topic:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3